# PHP: Add object to global namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Currently, I need to add `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;` in every file to use the database class.

Is there any way to add this to the globale namespace so I do not have to add this in every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a class alias (See http://php.net/class_alias )

So if you place this in your index it will know the DB class

`class_alias('Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager', 'DB');`